# Closing one process invoked from C# closes other processes

Tags: c#, windows, process

I'm starting a few processes from my C# application which have the same `.exe` and `WorkingDirectory`.

Process starting code:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = applicationInfo.ExePath,
    Arguments = configurationPathArguments,
    WorkingDirectory = applicationInfo.DllsDirectoryPath,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
};

Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = processStartInfo,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

process.Exited += OnProcessExited;
process.Start();
```

When I kill one of the processes in the windows Task Manager, sometimes more than one of them is killed.

***This happens even when my `OnProcessExited` `event` handle is empty.***

Am I invoking the processes in a wrong way?

Why would windows kill irrelevant processes that I didn't ask the task manager to kill when I am killing my process.

Comment: _"Why would windows kill irrelevant processes that I didn't ask the task manager to kill when I am killing my process"_ - it doesn't. Perhaps the application you're killing does this.

Comment: The application I'm killing is made by me and it doesn't, that's why I'm riddled...

Answer (score 1):

Using the provided code I was able to launch multiple winform.exe processes and terminate them in task manager with no problems.

There may be some shared functionality that is causing the remaining processes to crash.
Try attaching a debugger to the processes before terminating them and see if an exception gets raised.

You can also use DebugDiag to attach to running processes and save crash dump information https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2580960

Comment: Ty, i'll try it.  When im trying to kill 1 notepad from 10 i invoked, the problem doesnt exist.

Comment: I tried to attach 1 process by visual studio debugger, and no exception was thrown on the process exit. Anything else  guys?

Comment: So you ran two processes, attached a debugger to one and killed the other and the attached debugging process terminated without error? I'm pretty sure it is a code issue, task manager only terminates what you tell it to. You may have to add trace logic in the application exiting code to see how you are getting there.